# how to add empty first value and set it as null appcompat Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-databinding, android-appcompat

i create in a two way data binding spinner in Android, and added value into with a result of a REST GET.

I need now to add the first value of the spinner as an empty string that when it will be selected from the spinner, the value will be null.

In the fragment class i wrote this code:

```
//spinner 
appCompatSpinner = binding.spinner;
spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), viewModel.usersDetailsList );
appCompatSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerActorAdapter);

appCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      viewModel.onSelected(position);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

  }
});

mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Can someone please help me to achieve that?

Comment: You have to add it to `usersDetailsList` at 0 index .this is the only way i guess.

Comment: Done that with usersDetailsList.add(0, null); thanks Don't know how to set your reply as the acepted one.

Comment: Haha .. tell me one thing why you want to have first item as null ?? For setting hint to spinner ?

Comment: I don't want to have this first value of the spinner null (i know that now is null), the first value should be the default item and it's value when choosen should be equal to an empty string. But if i set " " to the value it is not correct. How can i assign this value to default empty string when choosen?